# Parse.com - Pointer to self - Parent/Child

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

I was creating a class in parse that references itself, and I don't seem to be able to retrieve the parent when using the javascript sdk or the rest api. Does anyone know if this is possible using parse? Should I be structuring my data in a different way? An example of my class is below. I didn't want to have a separate class for sub categories considering they are the same structure as the top level categories.

```
ProductCategory
  name (string)
  description (string)
  parentCategory (pointer to ProductCategory)
```

And this is how I am trying to pull the data using the javascript SDK:

```
var ProductCategory = parse.Object.extend("ProductCategory");
var query = new parse.Query(ProductCategory);

query.include('parentCategory');

query.find()
```

And here is trying to use the REST api (notice there is no parentCategory returned):

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ProductCategory?include=parentCategory' --header 'content-type: application/json' --header 'x-parse-application-id: blah' --header 'x-parse-rest-api-key: blah'

{
    "results": [
        {
            "createdAt": "2015-05-29T07:27:05.745Z",
            "name": "Category 1",
            "objectId": "skrxpy2ogU",
            "updatedAt": "2015-07-20T03:39:45.567Z"
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2015-05-29T07:27:12.603Z",
            "name": "Category 1.1",
            "objectId": "G37aLflfgQ",
            "updatedAt": "2015-05-29T07:28:06.764Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is obviously the way it should generally work. I will start searching for some Info about this ;)

Comment: I found something interesting about the console.log behaviour https://parse.com/questions/javascript-query-include-doesnt-work this isnt it though?

Comment: @MaxBumaye I'm not using console.log at all for this. The curl request shows it as raw as it is going to be.

Comment: Yeah, now that you have added the curl request/result I can see that